# 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option' python + pytest + selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

Пишу тест на pytest, в config.py написал обработчик для Chrome и Firefox, который считывает из командной строки параметр language, что бы запускать тест на разных языках. Вопрос, когда запускаю тест на браузере Firefox все работает, тесты идут на том языке, который указал, а когда на Chorme, то получаю ошибку 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'
Хотя я указал атрибут этот, шо делать?[image: вот сам код]

Comment: А `Options` откуда импортированы? Это `selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions`?

Comment: @hoefling уже разобрался, было импортировано  и Chrome Options, и ChromeOptions)